# Get a notification when an SVG element is visible

Tags: svg

I have a web application with a large SVG that may contain thousands of high-resolution images.

I want to load them only when the user can actually see them, and not in advance. Is there any way for me to get an indication when an svg element becomes viewable?

Comment: check the element's position and see if it's within the visible canvas with javascript. Note that browsers do a lot of this for you anyway i.e. deferring image loading till they are visible so you may get no benefit at all here.

Comment: The browser loads the svg images before they're visible. Calculating the element's position is tricky, due to numerous svg transforms. I can do that, but I hoped there was a way to just get an event fired when an elements gets into view, or moved out of view.